# Uniform convergence on three intervals

Tags: real-analysis

Determine the uniformly convergence of   $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{(x-n)^2+1}$ on $(1, \infty), (0,1), (0, \frac{1}{2})$. Here is my solution: On $(1, \infty)$ it's not uniformly convergence by choosing $x=n$. I'm not sure about the other 2 cases.

Answer (score 0):

If $n \ge 2$ and $x \in [0,1]$ then $f_n(x) \le {1 \over (n-1)^2 +1 }$.